# How to render the Vue component to a another (new) page in Vue-js using router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Currently my App renders on the same page, but I want it to render to a new page. I tried rendering by using `render: h => h(App)`, but it still renders on the same page.

Here's the Vue file from where the router will be linked (Risks.vue):

```
<router-link to="/risk-info">
<td>{{item.Model}}</td>
<td>{{item.Vulnerability}}</td>
<td>{{item.Unresolved}}</td>
</router-link>
<router-view/>
```

The below file links my router to the Component (index.js):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/risk-info',
    name: 'RiskInfo',
    component: () => import('../components/breakdown/risks/VulnerabilityDetails.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

And lastly, this is the file that defines the Vue object (main.js):

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  store,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Please can you be more specific with what you want to achieve? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I have added these things in the question. Thanks @Simon

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, how can you open the link in a new tab, then you can use the `target` attribute on a `<router-link>`

```
<router-link to="/risk-info" target="_blank">...</router-link>
```

Although obviously you'll lose any application state, as it'll load a new instance of your app.

Comment: Is it possible that Component could open on the same tab but as a new page?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. You want the page address to change along with the page content? Isn't that what happens with your current code?

Comment: What happens right now is it shows up along with the other elements on the same page, what I want is that it opens as if its a new page where previous page components dont exist.

Comment: Sounds like you might have put your 'home' page content actually in the page that contains the `<router-view>` component? If you put it in it's own page component, and add a default route, it should be swapped out when the URL changes.

Comment: Yeah @NilsonJacques , you’re absolutely correct! It would be really nice of you, if you could upvote my question too. Thanks 